# Ant task capture image extensions using jpg|png

Tags: regex, ant, ant-contrib

Rewriting this now that I know what's going on more clearly:

I've got some Ant propertyregex tasks that extract three properties from image links in files. Then I want to use these to rewrite the links.

What I have so far extracts the properties I need, and then if I follow that with a replaceregex task I can use the properties to rewrite the links. However, even though the replaceregex will operate one line at a time, finishing one, then starting over at the next one, it takes the properties that were extracted from the first link and uses them as the replacements in every link in the file.

Is there a way to combine these two, so that the entire operation starts at one link, extracts properties, rewrites it, then moves to the next link and starts everything over?

Here's what I've got:

```
<project name="BuildModule" basedir="." default="extract.stuff">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
<property environment="env" />
<loadfile property="file" srcfile="${basedir}/inputLog.log"/>
<target name="extract.stuff">
    <for param="line" delimiter="${line.separator}" list="${file}">
        <sequential>

            <propertyregex property="imageName" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class.*?graphics/)(.*?jpg|png)" select="\2" />
            <propertyregex property="width" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class)(.*?)(width.*?)(alt)" select="\3" />
            <propertyregex property="alt" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class)(.*?)(width.*?)(alt=)(.*?)(/&gt;)" select="\5" />

        </sequential>
    </for>


     <replaceregexp byline="true">
      <regexp pattern="(&lt;img class)(.*?$)"/>
     <substitution expression="\&lt;ac:image ac:title=${alt} ac:${width}&gt;&lt;ri:attachment ri:filename=&quot;${imageName}&quot;&gt;&lt;ri:page ri:content-title=&quot;acme_shared_graphics&quot; /&gt;&lt;/ri:attachment&gt;&lt;/ac:image&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"/>
     <fileset dir=".">
     <include name="**.log"/>
     </fileset>
   </replaceregexp>

</target>
```

The links in the input file are like this:

```
<p class="p"><img class="image" id="concept_kdv_4zf_k4__image_qt1_pvc_q4" src="../../../shared_assets/acme_shared_graphics/acme_image_test.jpg" width="400" alt="Some alt title text"/></p>
```

and the result is this:

```
<p class="p"><ac:image ac:title="Some alt title text" ac:width="400" ><ri:attachment ri:filename="acme_image_test.jpg"><ri:page ri:content-title="acme_shared_graphics" /></ri:attachment></ac:image></p>
```

Once I get this working, I'm hoping that the `(.*?jpg|png)` option will work as well, extracting either `image_name.jpg` or `image_name.png` depending on which the link contains, then replacing it the same way.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I have now, after the help here:

```
<project name="BuildModule" basedir="." default="extract.stuff">

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

<property environment="env" />
<loadfile property="file" srcfile="${basedir}/inputLog.log"/>

<target name="extract.stuff">

    <for param="line" delimiter="${line.separator}" list="${file}">

        <sequential>

        <propertyregex override="true" property="imageName" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class.*?graphics/)(.*?jpg|png)" select="\2" />
        <propertyregex override="true" property="width" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class)(.*?)(width.*?)(alt)" select="\3" />
        <propertyregex override="true" property="alt" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class)(.*?)(width.*?)(alt=)(.*?)(/&gt;)" select="\5" />  

        <replaceregexp byline="true">
        <regexp pattern="(&lt;img class)(.*?$)"/>
        <substitution expression="\&lt;ac:image ac:title=${alt} ac:${width}&gt;&lt;ri:attachment ri:filename=&quot;${imageName}&quot;&gt;&lt;ri:page ri:content-title=&quot;BSW_shared_graphics&quot; /&gt;&lt;/ri:attachment&gt;&lt;/ac:image&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"/>

        <!-- 
        <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**.log"/>
        </fileset>
        -->

        </replaceregexp>

        </sequential>

    </for>

</target>
```

Commenting out the `<fileset></fileset>` in the `<replaceregexp>` is an attempt to make everything run according to input specified in the `<for>` loop, since the problem was that the `<replaceregexp>` using a fileset was doing the entire file, line by line, before returning to the `<propertyregex>` section. However now, without the `<fileset>`, the build just ignores the `<replaceregexp>` section. If I put `<fileset>` back in, it acts as before, changing each property to the first encountered in the file.

Adding override to the `<propertyregex>` fixed the problem about retaining the property, so I don't need `<unset>`.

Comment: `However now, without the <fileset>, the build just ignores the <replaceregexp> section`.. thats because u're not giving any ***input*** to the `<replaceregexp>` task to ***match-n-replace*** (`<fileset>` was earlier providing the input in the form of files to operate on). so, do this: `<replaceregexp file="${basedir}/inputLog.log" byline="true">..</..>` ***or decomment*** the `<fileset>` and *optionally* change to this `<include name="inputLog.log/>`

Comment: i suggested to remove `<fileset>` earlier to avoid extra files there (apart from the relevant `inputLog.log` and such files) from being processed. if replacement is needed in one/more files, try to avoid unneeded `.log` files that reside in the `fileset basedir`, by being careful with the `<include>` tag.

Comment: you may change the `regex pattern` to directly match `@{line}`: `<replaceregexp file="..." byline="true"> <regexp pattern="@{line}"/>...`  and do include `override="true"`

Comment: also, i must say that this approach will work (maybe with a little tweaking) but i wont recommend it to you. the `<propertyregex>` loops over `${file}` and in ***each*** iteration of the `<for>` loop, the `<replaceregexp>` scans it's ***input file*** line by line till a match/end-of-file is reached. these extra iterations can be completely avoided with the ***grouping approach***

Comment: Okay thanks for all the help. I understand now. I will use the grouping approach-- in fact I already had a solution before posting the question using replaceregex only, without properties involved, but as I say I wanted to learn how to do this with properties, or see if I could.  My original solution took mutiple replaceregex operations, so your grouping idea is better, and I'll use it. I'll keep experimenting with the properties approach because it's a learning experience. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `<for>` loop has ended before `<replaceregexp>` therefore you aren't really extracting values for `${imageName}, ${width} and ${alt}` for every line for the `<replaceregexp>` task.  thus, they aren't changing and would probably retain the values of the **FIRST** line gone through by `<propertyregex>` due to the missing `override="true"`.

therefore, either include the `<replaceregexp>` task within `<for><sequential></..></..>`, as shown in the next answer, or, instead of specifying `imageName, width and alt` in the `<substitution>` expression... specify groups, such as `\2, \5, \X..` and replace the `<regex>` pattern string with one that incorporates the entire line of the file.

such as:

```
<regexp pattern="&lt;img class.*?/(.*?graphics)/(.*?)&quot; width=&quot;(.*?)&quot; -alt=&quot;(.*?)&quot;/&gt;"/>
<substitution expression="\&lt;ac:image ac:title=&quot;\4&quot; ac:&quot;\3&quot;&gt;&lt;ri:attachment ri:filename=&quot;\2&quot;&gt;&lt;ri:page ri:content-title=&quot;\1&quot; /&gt;&lt;/ri:attachment&gt;&lt;/ac:image&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"/>
```

---

**EDIT:**

`propertyregex` already allows for ***mutability*** of *properties*. thus, `imageName, alt and width` are fine and can be changed (***just add `override="true"` as an attribute - `<propertyregex ... override="true".../>`and you wont need any `unset="true"`***).

the reason you were getting only the `first line values for every line` for `imageName, alt and width` is that `<propertyregex>` was missing the `override="true"`, therefore the first time these properties were being set, they remained **unchanged** in the subsequent loops of `<for>`
so now,

-- include `<replaceregexp>` within `<sequential>`.
 -- add `override` to all three properties: `<propertyregex .. override="true".. />`

(and also, your current `<replaceregexp>` runs for ***all*** the files in the `<fileset>`. if you include it within `<sequential>` make sure to avoid irrelevant files in the `fileset basedir` from getting picked up by the `<include name= regex>`)

and it should work.

**OR,** try the `grouping` method i mentioned. i would have gone with this one.
here, i think, you ***wont need any*** `<for> & <propertyregexp>` at all. just run (within the `target`) **only** with the `<replaceregexp>` task over the entire `<fileset>`, like you have, BUT change the `<regex pattern` and `<substitution expression` to accommodate ***groupings***.

infact, if you look closely, all that `<propertyregex>` does is select the **`relevant groupings`** from its input lines and your-implementation-of-`<replaceregexp>` replaces those values in the files/lines. ***combine these two by using groupings in the `<replaceregexp>` task itself.***

refer [HERE](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) for more on `<replaceregexp>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, see my comments below. I might try your second solution also, but I'm curious to see if I can get variables working at all because I can use the tactic in other places, also just for my own learning purposes.

Comment: `unset` can be used as an *attribute* of the `<var>` task. u'll need to include *ant-contrib.jar*. for eg: `<property name="x" value="6"/> <echo>${x}</echo>   <!-- will print 6 -->`  
`<var name="x" unset="true"/><property name="x" value="12"/>
    <echo>${x}</echo>   <!-- will print 12 -->`   for ***var & unset***: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html  
for ***ant-contrib*** here: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thx, I realized that, after I read the variable task page again. Okay so I seem to have the ant-contrib jar as a resource, because `propertyregex` is an ant-contrib task and it's been working from the start. If I insert `<var name="imageName" unset="true"/>` just after the opening `<sequential>` in my project, or anywhere else inside of `<sequential></sequential>`, it doesn't seem to unset the variable, the behavior is as before. If I insert it anywhere outside of `<sequential></sequential>` I get errors.

Comment: `<var name="imageName" unset="true"/>` does seem to be functioning; as a test I inserted it after the `<propertyregex property="imageName"[....]` line, and that way the build replaces the imagename as `"${imageName}"` instead of the image file name. That is, it does seem to unset what was just set in the line before it. I just need it to do that when placed before the property is named, but not working so far.

Comment: Thx again. Regarding: `[...]<replaceregexp> ... change it to serve each line at a time due to the <for> loop[...]` How? I had been wondering about that also, so I removed all of `<fileset>[...]</fileset>` from the `<replaceregexp>` group but it then just runs the `<propertyregex>' part. `<replaceregexp>` is inside `<sequential>` now, thus also inside of `<for>`

Comment: `<replaceregexp match="&lt;img class.*?/(.*?graphics)/(.*?)&quot; width=&quot;(.*?)&quot; -alt=&quot;(.*?)&quot;/&gt;" replace="&lt;ac:image ac:title=&quot;\4&quot; ac:&quot;\3&quot;&gt;&lt;ri:attachment ri:filename=&quot;\2&quot;&gt;&lt;ri:page ri:content-title=&quot;\1&quot; /&gt;&lt;/ri:attachment&gt;&lt;/ac:image&gt;&lt;/p&gt;" byline="true">
    <fileset dir="${html.dir}" includes="**/*.html"/>
</replaceregexp>`  
edit ***fileset*** and ***include*** as per your context

Comment: **correction:** *remove* fileset and include as per your context

Comment: Sorry that wasn't what I meant, I understood how to do the second suggestion, using groups instead of properties. I was asking about this sentence from you: `and also, your current <replaceregexp> runs for all the files in the <fileset>. if you include it within <sequential> make sure to change it to serve each line at a time due to the <for> loop...` (end quote). I thought you were suggesting that as part of making the propertyregex approach work. I'll put what I have now in an edit in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

In Ant properties once set are immutable by design, so you need to unset your properties first, using antcontrib [unset](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html). Then you'll get your replaceregexp stuff working within for loop :

```
    <for param="line" delimiter="${line.separator}" list="${file}">
     <sequential>

      <var name="imageName" unset="true"/>
      <var name="width" unset="true"/>
      <var name="alt" unset="true"/>

      <propertyregex property="imageName" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class.*?graphics/)(.*?jpg|png)" select="\2" />
      <propertyregex property="width" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class)(.*?)(width.*?)(alt)" select="\3" />
      <propertyregex property="alt" input="@{line}" regexp="(&lt;img class)(.*?)(width.*?)(alt=)(.*?)(/&gt;)" select="\5" />

      <replaceregexp>
       <!-- ... -->
      </replaceregexp>

     </sequential>
    </for>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried putting the replaceregexp inside `<for></for>`, but had gotten an error, but I realized after reading your response and the other one that it needed to be inside `<sequential>` as well. \

Comment: (Ran out of edit time...) However now, when using your suggestion I'm getting `Failed to create type or task unset. The name is undefined.` Does this mean that `unset`, or I guess `variable` task, is not included in my ant-contrib library? I have the Ant version installed as part of Oxygen XML, and the Ant-contrib jar inside seems to be 1.0b3, not the most recent but the one before that. I got a little confused trying to figure out how to replace it with a download, I don't see a .jar file in the latest download of 1.0b5.

Comment: Oops, sorry - of course it has to be <var name="nameofyourproperty" unset="true"/> instead => fixed it in my answer.